# Failed to execute 'scrollTo' on 'Window': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present

Tags: javascript, meteor

I feel like I'm really close to having this plugin work in my application. The error i'm running into happens each time I press on one of my nav bar elements. Any thoughts as to why this error is occurring?

### Error

Failed to execute 'scrollTo' on 'Window': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present.

### Markdown

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="hidden">
            <a href="./#top"></a>
          </li>

          <!--
                  <li>
                      <a class="page-scroll" href="#missions">Why</a>
                  </li> -->


          <li> <a class="page-scroll" id="missions" href="#missions">How</a> </li>

          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" id="p2s" href="#p2s">What</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" id="footer" href="#footer">Sign-up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
```

### JS logic

```
Meteor.startup(function() {


  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  controller.scrollTo(function(target) {
    TweenMax.to(window, 0.5, {
      scrollTo: {
        y: target, 
        autoKill: true
      },
      ease: Cubic.easeInOut
    });


  console.log("in here");

  });


  $(document).on("click", "a[href^=#]", function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr("href");

  if($(id).length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // trigger scroll
    controller.scrollTo(id);

    // If supported by the browser we can also update the URL
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
      history.pushState("", document.title, id);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: A stab in the dark: `scrollTo: {
        x:0,
        y: target, 
        autoKill: true
      },`

Comment: I thought that was it by adding an x value. It is still returning the same error.